# Move the css and javascript file to another website

Tags: web, cdn, traffic

if I have (website A) instead I put my CSS and java script file in the (website A) move it to (website B ) what is the effect of this process? does the existing web traffic on (website A) move to (website B ) ?

Answer (score 0):

partially - yes, also the site a will load faster, because requests will be served not by one, but 2 servers.

this is how https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network works

Comment: I need to increase a web traffic on the (web site B) does this process do what i want?\

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but yes, if you change the link of your css/js assets from Site A to Site B, the request to Site A will

1. Browser load the main html page from Site A's server
2. Browser load assets from Site B's server

When you mention you want increase the web traffic of Site B, what exact goal are you make?

Since you have mentioned CDN as a tag, you may talking about reduce the server load of Site A's server. If this is the case, then changing the links to Site B will be helpful to reduce the server load. However, you may also adopt a real CDN to help you, there are many free/cheap services available you can try out.

Also thinking about the performance of Site A, you may not get what you want. Because you will only requests all the assets after step 1 of the request of the main html page. And the overhead of more Site B's DNS resolution may slow down your performance even further.